# Отправка формы на определённый e-mail в зависимости от выбранной radiobutton

Tags: wordpress, form, contact-form7

Сайт на wordpress. Форма сделана с помощью модуля contact-form-7.
В форме есть радиокнопки. Нужно привязать радиокнопки к e-mail на которые будет уходить заявка.
Как я понимаю сам модуль contact-form-7 не позволяет это сделать в админке WP и нужно менять обработчик js.

Подскажите как реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается такой функционал есть. Делается вот так:

```
[select your-recipient "CEO|ceo@example.com"
                    "Sales|sales@example.com"
                    "Support|support@example.com"]
```

Потом [your-recipient] вставляется в send mail to.

Значение до pipe берется через вот такую структуру: [*raw*{field name}] ([_raw_your-recipient] - для примера выше.

Comment: Увлекательный тут диалог ))) Отредактируйте свой ответ, добавив туда текст из комментария, а комментарий удалите)